# Getting current entry element via plugin in Craft 3 without a hook

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, hook

Is it possible to query the current entry or category element via a Craft 3 plugin/module?

In the 2.6 era, I would use a hook. The Craft 3 iteration of a hook looks something like this:

```
$currentElement;

Craft::$app->getView()->hook('someHook', function(array &$context) {
  if (isset($context['entry'])) {
    $currentElement = $context['entry'];
  } else if (isset($context['category'])) {
    $currentElement = $context['category'];
  }
});
```

With an accompanying Twig snippet in the template:

```
{% hook 'someHook' %}
```

I'm wondering if there is a cleaner practice to accomplish the same goal? I find relying on Twig snippet reduces the flexibility of my plugin.

I've noticed the [SEOMatic](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic) plugin is able to append entry specific data without any hooks in the template. I can't figure out how, but it gives me hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `Craft::$app->getElements()->getElementByUri()` -- or you might also use `Craft::$app->getUrlManager()->getMatchedElement()` depending on your use case.

- Your friendly neighborhood SEOmatic author :)

Comment: From the man himself! Thanks Andrew, this is exactly what I've bene after.

Comment: No prob. Updated the answer with another possibility for you too, depending on what you're trying to do.